Voltage doubler waveforms
A voltage doubler is connected like this (the voltage source in series with the inductor simulates transformer output):

After stepping the load (100k, 1M, 10M, 100M, 1000M) the waveforms look like this:

The "transformer output" voltage V(2) always has some sort of a plateau, even when under very light load. What causes the plateau and can its height be calculated/estimated for different loads?
I can also see something like ringing on V(2), is this caused by the capacitance of the diodes or is it something else?
EDIT:
Based on comments I'm adding another simulated schematic, where I used a real transformer (FL2015-3L, https://www.coilcraft.com/getmedia/6651db01-d153-47d9-8a27-4758c28bff0d/fl.pdf):

The simulated V(2) then looks like this:

I used a coupling factor of 0.9849 corresponding to leakage inductance being 3% of the secondary's inductance (0.03*190mH = 5.7mH). I have also checked this using 5.7mH in my "inductor schematic" above and got exactly the same waveform as with the transformer.
So yes, I was wrong in using the whole secondary inductance instead of just the leakage inductance and the plateau height was too low as a result. However, even with the 5.7mH leakage inductance (or the complete transformer) the two effects (plateau and ringing) are clearly visible and my original questions remain.
PS: I neglected the transformer's auxiliary winding, which is used in a Baxandall (though usually called somewhat confusingly Royer) oscillator. In my design the secondary voltage amplitude was actually 1kV but I brought it down to 200V in my example simulation so as to have high-voltage diode with a built-in LTspice model whose maximum reverse voltage wouldn't interfere with the circuit.

My bet is that the inductor (200 mH) is far, far too high so, what is the justification? It would also help immensely if your waveforms were on a white background.

@Andyaka OK, I have made the backround white. The inductor value is 200mH because it is the inductance of my transformer. I was actually seeing the plateaus on my transformer's secondary, which is connected to a 6x multiplier (I have simplified by question to a double). And this made me wonder...

Are you saying that the secondary leakage inductance of your transformer is 200 mH? I find it hard to believe this figure but, anyway, you can prove this to yourself by lowering it to maybe 200 nH (in your simulator)and watching the effect. Then if you are able to justify 200 mH then please also do that. I just have serious doubts that something producing a 200 volt peak at 50 kHz will have 200 mH (that's millihenries) leakage inductance.

Simulate the transformer with a transformer, not an inductor .

You mention a 6x multiplier, but do not say what kind it is (Dickson, Cockroft-Walton, Hybrid), nor include its schematic. Why don't you ask another question. (Not sure what you're asking here).

@MicroservicesOnDDD What I really used is a 6x Cockroft-Walton multiplier but I simplified the question to a doubler ( i.e. 2x Cockroft-Walton multiplier). I might ask another question with the 6x multiplier but I thought the phenomena I am asking about (plateau, ringing) are visible with a doubler too (or an inductor) and may be easier to describe/explain/calculate.

Is the plateau something you're trying to feature, e.g. music synthesis, or is it something that you're trying to suppress? Also, are you just learning this, or do you have a specific application in mind? To get rid of the plateau,   without understanding myself what's causing it, try a hybrid, and a bipolar would be more efficient if you can use it.

@Andyaka -- how much leakage inductance would you expect?

The op has detailed this if you look at the edited question.

@Andyaka -- I want to learn from the expert, not the person asking the question.

@MicroservicesOnDDD It very much depends on the coupling factor of the two coils and, the data sheet isn't very clear about that nor is it very clear about the primary inductance measurements so, it's a tricky one.

@Andyaka Coilcraft say in https://www.coilcraft.com/en-us/models/howto/simulation-model-considerations-part-ii-(1)/ they do not publish transformer models but they have a general comment about leakage inductance being about 3% of primary inductance (Effects of Including DCR and Leakage Inductance, 1st paragraph). I took this ballpark value to calculate the coupling factor for the LTspice transformer model.

@MicroservicesOnDDD I am trying to understand the mechanism of the plateau. My application is a high voltage supply. The plateau may have a negative effect as it lowers the multiplied output voltage. It is the maximum level which is multiplied (in my simulation doubled). Without the plateau the shape of the waveform would be more sine-like, its peak value higher and the doubled output voltage close to 400 V. I don't know if I can get rid of it as it seems to be determined by the load, which is given.

@Hyp before the inductance lowered, the waveforms look a lot different to afterwards so, given that the original posting contained information that is faulty AND, nobody has made an answer yet, why not simplify this post, dump the original stuff and, stick with the new waveforms/circuit. Also, if the plateau question is still valid, can you explain what part of the waveform it applies to. Also explain what scenarios the five colours relate to.

If you break a square wave up into its components, you end up with a series of sine waves. Of course, this is just a mathematical thing, and you can reverse the process, which is what I believe you are seeing.
